# Why is making a notification slow?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm creating an app for Android, and it is not listed in the market, so I made my own updater.

An Asynctask runs in the background checking for a new version. When there is a new version it creates a notification.

When the notification is in the status bar, opening the status bar is slow (and sometimes clicking on the notification won't work).

Here is my code:

```
public static void makeNotification(Class<?> newclass,
                                    CharSequence msg,
                                    CharSequence from,
                                    CharSequence message,
                                    int icon, Context c) {
    PendingIntent newintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, new Intent(c, newclass), 0);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = new Notification(icon, msg, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(c, from, message, newintent);

    nm.notify(0, notif);
}
```

This is in the main activity and gets called from the asynctask.

```
if (Integer.parseInt(xmlroosters.getVersionCode()) > currentversion) {
    new Main().makensNotification(Update.class,
                                  "The app needs an update.",
                                  "Update",
                                  "Click here to update the app.",
                                  R.drawable.app);
}
```

Why is this slow? (Sometimes I can't even open the status bar) and why sometimes clicking on it isn't even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're calling that over and over in a loop.  You're consuming all your phone's available CPU cycles checking for an update ;)

Consider checking on a schedule ...

```
new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: Does an asynctask run more than once?

Comment: the code for the notification is in an if loop -> check edited question

Comment: No, but how is it just sitting there waiting for an update?  The AsyncTask() contains a loop that watching for an update?

Comment: Yep ... you're basically looping over that code as fast as your device or emulator can muster.  You need to check on a period other than while (!error) { // }

Comment: ah youre right:) code wasnt finished yet but I already tested it, need to break out of that loop when finsihed, Thank you!